# reactjs make https (not http) requests with axios

Tags: reactjs, https, axios

I'm trying to make https requests to the server using axios. Most of the tutorials regarding axios specify how to make http requests.
I make the requests whenever users login. Here is my current request:

```
axios.post('/api/login/authentication', {
  email: email,
  password: password
})
.then(response => {
  this.props.history.push('/MainPage')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

Can anyone help me convert this to an https request?

Comment: If your server has a https certificate, it should automatically default to that

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All URLs have two parts

1. Domain - `http://yourdomain.com`
2. Path - `/path-to-your-endpoint`

#### 1. Use default domain

In `axios`, if you specify just the `path`, it will use the domain in the address bar by default.

For example, the code below will make a call to whatever domain is in your address bar and append this path to it. If the domain is `http`, your api request will be a `http` call and if the domain is `https`, the api request will be a `https` call. Usually `localhost` is `http` and you will be making `http` calls in `localhost`.

```
axios.post('/api/login/authentication', {
```

#### 2. Specify full URL with domain

On the other hand, you can pass full URL to axios request and you will be making `https` calls by default.

```
axios.post('https://yourdomain.com/api/login/authentication', {
```

#### 2. Use axios baseURL option

You can also set `baseURL` in axios

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  baseURL: 'https://yourdomain.com/api/',
  url: '/login/authentication',
  data: {
    email: email,
    password: password
  }
}).then(response => {
  this.props.history.push('/MainPage')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm getting the errors: `Failed to load resource: An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made.` and  `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://localhost:3000/api/login/authentication due to access control checks.` could this be another issue or one related to how I'm sending the request

Comment: Can you open that HTTPS Url in your browser? Do you get any SSL certificate errors? Are you sure the port number is correct (it cannot be the same as for HTTP)?

Comment: The error you are facing is not related to the request. 1. localhost is usually only `http`. 2. To enable `https` you need to setup certificates in your server.

Answer (score 0):

This may also work

```
 headers: {
        scheme: 'https',
      },
```