# How do I fix a network error received from axios response reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm making a post request using axios in reactjs after users login. Here it is:

```
axios.post('https://localhost:3000/api/login/authentication', {
  email: email,
  password: password
})
.then(response => {
  this.props.history.push('/Main')
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

It goes in the error and I log it to the console. This is what I get:

`Error: "Network Error"
createErrorhttp://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:26742:15 handleErrorhttp://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:26293:14`

Also in case it's any help, I get this warning before the error:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://localhost:3000/api/login/authentication. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed)`

Can anyone please help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `https` with `localhost`? You need to setup certificates before using `https`. [Check this post](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-get-https-working-on-your-local-development-environment-in-5-minutes-7af615770eec)

Comment: Also, `CORS` is a header that needs to be set from the server end. Although if `localhost` is throwing `CORS`, it must be either the API server is running on a different port than the server that sends the page or it must be `https` in the url.

Comment: Also, the question and example looks very similar to [reactjs make https (not http) requests with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576923/reactjs-make-https-not-http-requests-with-axios/53577131?noredirect=1#comment94018568_53577131), although from different users.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using a front-end application that makes request to a back-end API, you need to include certain headers in the API server if the API server is running on a different port.

For example, if you're serving a ReactJS application with webpack in development mode, webpack acts as a server, sending the reactJS application to the client. Then, making requests to the API server will require that the API server, running on a different port, include Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in all http responses.

Basically, before generating every response, you need to set `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` to `localhost:<port you visit in the browser>`.

In a basic express app, you can paste this in your `app.js` file, for example:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3001');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  );
  next();
});
```

Note: If you may need to change `http://localhost:3001` to match the port you visit in the browser.

EDIT: OP is not using express, but is using Webpack. The question is: What is an express-agnostic solution?

Answer: The solution is still the same: regardless of what API server you are using, just set the response headers for every response.

There is another solution that involves Webpack, though:

In the `package.json` file of your front end code that's being served with webpack, add the following: `"proxy" :"http://localhost:<port API server is running on>"`

For example, is webpack is serving your front end app to `localhost:3000` and your api server is running on `localhost:3001`, then the proxy in `package.json` would be:

`"proxy":"http://localhost:3001"`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. My app is not express. I do use webpack though. Can you provide a solution with webpack?

Comment: Updated my answer, providing a webpack-specific workaround as well as an api-server-agnostic approach.

Comment: I already do the proxy in my package.json but where do I setup the headers for the response?

Comment: In your API server code. Do you have a repo? If so I can clone it and show you what I mean

Comment: I have a repo however, it's private and can't be shared for security reasons. Thanks for the answer though, I'll look more into this and see if I can figure out where the code belongs

Answer (score 0):

You can add the CORS header in webpack dev server config as follows:

```
headers: {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
},
```

This will add these two headers in your response. Hence solve your problem. However, when your services run on a different server other than your local machine, these headers need to be added in server response.

Comment: where can I find the webpack dev server config? In the `node_modules` file, i found the `webpack-dev-server` folder. Am I going in the right direction?

Comment: @tee create a file webpack.config.js, install webpack-dev-server and pass the file webpack.config.js in npm start script. I feel you need to know about webpack first.

Comment: yes I'm fairly new to reactjs as a whole. I installed webpack-dev-server but can you show me how my webpack.config.js file should look like and how I should call it?

Comment: @tee Stack is not the platform to ask for code/solutions. Its to discuss technical queries. You need to learn baiscs and then go into dev. Read stackoverflow's usage policy.

Answer (score 0):

1. The very first thing that i am figuring out in your code is that you are using 'https' but it should be only 'http'to make request, because local host uses http.

2)This might be due to cors, Before making any requests , the browser sends a pre-flight request to the API server to know that "This website has been allowed to access your resources or not", so using cors and specifying origin which can access API resources will solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea, it might help you. I was having the same issue "Network Error" while accessing newroutes API endpoints from react UI, after moving newroutes definition after api route (in node API server), issue got resolved, like below:

```
var app = express();
var api = require('./api')
var newRoutes = require('./services/newRoutes/default');

api({ app: app });
**app.use('/newroutes/list', newRoutes);**
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because I have used wrong structure in app.js (main file).

Error occurred by doing this:

```
app.use('/api/v1',user)

export const instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id : "*******",
    key_secret : "******"
})
```

Error removed by doing this:

```
export const instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id : "********",
    key_secret : "********"
})

app.use('/api/v1',user)
```

1. - Reason is that always try to have Structured Approach
2. - Always look what your putting at time needs additional data like some above
     example
     That specific route at some point down there needs razorpay instance info,
     So that's the reason put secret at the top and then route otherwise error is in front of your space