# Network Error making post request using Axios

Tags: json, react-native, post, axios

I'm trying to make my application sending a post request and receiving a response using Axios. However i encoutered errors while trying to make a post request.

My code for making post request:

```
onPostJson = () => {
  axios.post('https://10.1.127.17:11111/vpdu/get-ca-thu-hoi',
  {
    FromDate: "01-Jan-2020",
    ToDate: "01-Feb-2020",
    Ca: 1
  })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.json());
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Error:

```
Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:80:22 in handleError
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:39 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:574:29 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:388:25 in __didCompleteResponse
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:190:12 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:436:47 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:111:26 in __guard$argument_0
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:384:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:110:17 in __guard$argument_0
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I suspected that there is problem with the URL, but i successfully made a post request to this URL using Postman.

**Solution**: It was syntax error. I forgot to include Header configurations in the code.

```
onPostJson = () => {
      console.log("onpost");
      axios.post('http://10.1.127.17:11111/vpdu/get-ca-thu-hoi', {
        FromDate: "01-Jan-2020",
        ToDate: "01-May-2020",
      }, {
            headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImtpZW50ZC5haXRzIiwibmJmIjoxNTkzNzY0MDU0LCJleHAiOjE1OTQzNjg4NTQsImlhdCI6MTU5Mzc2NDA1NH0.liIM6g2E_EMXvnRpL1RcU-QVyUAKYxVLZZK05OqZ8Ck',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        })
        .then(respond => {
          // console.log(respond.data.CaThuHoiList);
          setShiftData(respond.data.CaThuHoiList);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log('Error');
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
axios.post('https://10.1.127.17:11111/vpdu/get-ca-thu-hoi', {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Accept: 'application/json',
        },
          FromDate: "01-Jan-2020",
          ToDate: "01-Feb-2020",
          Ca: 1
    });
```

i'm not sure, but ..

Do you want to try it like the code above?

Comment: `code`
Network Error
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:1:0 in <global>
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:73:25 in handleAbort
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

Comment: onPostJson().then((getInfo) => { 
Can you page me in this form?

Comment: I just wanted to implement a simple fuction making POST request, nothing to do with Authentication or Topics related to the link you sent me.

Comment: Oh, that's right.
I'm sorry!
If you can't solve the problem after seeing this link, can you let me know again?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576923/reactjs-make-https-not-http-requests-with-axios

Comment: That's cool.
I should do it the way you said it.
That's how I learned it.
Thank you.