# NodeJS Switching to axios from request: Credentials not passed

Tags: node.js, request, axios

so far I've been using request-promise which is now deprecated. I have chosen axios to be the successor and I adapted the code but unfortunately I keep getting error 401 "Unauthorized". It seems as if axios is not passing the auth info given. My old source code looks like this:

```
let options = {
  method: 'GET',
  uri: 'https://example.com/bla',
  auth: {
    user: 'USER',
    pass: 'PASSWORD',
    sendImmediately: true
  },
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch'
  },
  resolveWithFullResponse: true
};
let rpWithDefaults = rp.defaults({
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  jar: true
});
let response = await rpWithDefaults(options);
```

The adapted code snippet looks like this:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const https = require('https');
const response = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/bla',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch'
    },
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
      auth: {
        user: 'USER',
        pass: 'PASSWORD'
      }
    }),
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Axios doc says you need to pass this way.

```
  // `auth` indicates that HTTP Basic auth should be used, and supplies credentials.
  // This will set an `Authorization` header, overwriting any existing
  // `Authorization` custom headers you have set using `headers`.
  // Please note that only HTTP Basic auth is configurable through this parameter.
  // For Bearer tokens and such, use `Authorization` custom headers instead.
  auth: {
    username: 'janedoe',
    password: 's00pers3cret'
  },
```

So did you try just changing the key from `user` and `pass` to `username` and `password`

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const https = require('https');
const response = await axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://example.com/bla',
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch'
    },
    auth: {
       username: '<user-name>',
       password: '<password>'
    },
    resolveWithFullResponse: true
  });
```

Comment: Hell, I read this doc and checked the property name "auth" but I did not recognise the property names below. It works now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: it happens, Cool!

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the `httpsAgent` parameter before, but I don't think it's required to make https calls in Axios. Does the following work for you?

```
const axios = require('axios').default;
const response = await axios({
  method: 'GET',
  baseURL: 'https://example.com/',
  url: '/bla',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-Token': 'Fetch'
  },
  auth: {
    user: 'USER',
    pass: 'PASSWORD'
  }
});
```

Maybe relevant: [reactjs make https (not http) requests with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576923/reactjs-make-https-not-http-requests-with-axios)